# Variables in update-statement SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have a table like this;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    intRecnum int NULL,
    intAr int NULL,
    decJanuari decimal(5,2) NULL,
    decMars decimal(5,2) NULL,
    decMaj decimal(5,2) NULL,
    decOktober decimal(5,2) NULL,
    decNovember decimal(5,2) NULL,
    datSkapad datetime NULL,
    intSkapadAv int NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I want is to update the column decNovember.
Without variables it works fine;

```
  update TestTable
  set decnovember= '222.22'
  where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from TestTable where intAr = '2019')
  and decnovemberis null
```

But after adding variables it just says '(0 rows affected)'
This is how it looks right now;

```
DECLARE @MonthCol varchar(50);
    DECLARE @TEST varchar(50);
DECLARE @today datetime;

set @today = getdate();
set @MonthCol = 'dec';

set @MonthCol += FORMAT(@today, 'MMMM','sv-SE');

--just for testing 
set @TEST = @MonthCol;
--select @MonthCol,@TEST;


  update TestTable
  set @MonthCol = '111.11'
  where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from TestTable where intAr = '2019')
  and @TEST is null
```

Cant see what it is I'm missing out…

Comment: One can't use a variable for column names like that. You'll probably need to use Dynamic Sql for this one.  Also, why the sub-query on the same table when `and intAr = '2019'` would do?

Comment: IDK about you guys but this data structure smells of flatness and bad design. This query would be easy to solve if they werent columns that should be rows :|

Comment: @DougCoats, Totally agree on that, sadly not up to me.

Comment: @LukStorms, Well...could be my poor skills, but need to select the current year. Each row is a diffrent year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, havnt done any dynamic SQL before but it did the trick...Thanks!

Its not cleaned up yet, but something like this worked;

```
DECLARE @MonthCol varchar(50);
DECLARE @today datetime;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Value decimal(5,2);
DECLARE @year varchar(10);

set @today = getdate();
set @MonthCol = 'dec';
set @Value = '111.11'
set @MonthCol += FORMAT(@today, 'MMMM','sv-SE');
set @year = year(getdate());

set @SQL = N'
  update TestTable set ' +@MonthCol + '= ' +cast(@Value as nvarchar(20)) + ' where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from TestTable where intAr = '+ @year +') and ' +@MonthCol + ' is null';

 --select @SQL;
  exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: I would try and find another method. Dynamic SQL should not be used for something like this.

Comment: @ThomasH I would be tempted to use xml functions on the sys.objects table joined to sys.columns to convert columns to rows and then use what ever query is giving youre update-to value to tie into this pivoted query and hten update based off of that

Comment: Can you tell me how youre getting 222.22 from your example?

Comment: The value comes from a whole other story (ie Another complex Query). Cant say Ive used any xml-functions, so you've lost me there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sql server 2012 so `FORMAT` wouldn't work and your example doesn't have the schemas for `TestTable`, but something like this would update the variable.

You cannot update variables the same way you update a column.

```
DECLARE @MonthCol varchar(50);
    DECLARE @TEST varchar(50);
DECLARE @today datetime;

set @today = getdate();
set @MonthCol = 'dec';

set @MonthCol += FORMAT(@today, 'MMMM','sv-SE');

--just for testing 
set @TEST = @MonthCol;
--select @MonthCol,@TEST;

select @MonthCol = '111.11' from TestTable
where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from TestTable where intAr = '2019')
and @TEST is null

select @MonthCol
```

Comment: sorry if I missunderstand you, but how does this update the table?
The variable is updated just fine...it was the update table i had problem with.

Comment: You said that with variables you had "(0 rows affected)" so I thought you were having trouble updating the variable.